# Is there a PCI scanning vendor with an API?

Tags: api, security, pci-compliance

We are looking for a PCI scanning vendor that supports an API that we can:

1) Update the list of IP's/domains via API calls

2) Perform scans regularly (on a schedule, or triggered)

3) Provide the results via API calls so we can automate generation of tickets around PCI compliance issues

It seems like this should be available somewhere in our age of API's.

Comment: Qualys (an ASV) have an API for scan scheduling/result management:   https://community.qualys.com/community/developer

Comment: Such questions seeking 3rd party resources are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vendors that I found that have a usable API are:

- Qualys - qualys.com
- Beyond Security - beyondsecurity.com
- Beyond Trust - beyondtrust.com